# Why is the graviton spin supposed to be 2, and how can it interact with matter?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-spin, field-theory, quantum-gravity

As far as I know, gravitons are predicted to be spin-2 particles because some extrapolation from GR about non-linearity and antisymmetry. I think I want some clarification on that.

What are some proposals on the explicit form of the Lagrangian?

Also, how does it affect massive fields? Does it couple in a similar way to photons and charge?

Comment: Please take a look at this:  [Can I ask several related questions in a single thread?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/9887)

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [How can I read off the fact that gravity is associated with spin-2 particles from the Einstein-Hilbert action?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108230/9887)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I'm sorry I broke a rule, I can take down the extra question in the middle

Comment: Related: [Linearizing the Einstein-Hilbert action; shortcuts?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440820/linearizing-the-einstein-hilbert-action-shortcuts)